# Assistance needed with message box

Tags: excel

Hi the below code works except for the message box, it still runs the code when the user clicks on "No" due to my lack of knowledge I cant see were its going wrong any assistance would be welcome

Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("V11:DM88")) <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Destination range is not empty"
Exit Sub
End If


Msg = "Do you want to continue ?"            ' Define message.
Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2 ' Define buttons.
Title = "Warning, This Action Canot be undone Once Accepted!  " ' Define title.
'Help = "DEMO.HLP"    ' Define Help file.
Ctxt = 1000                                  ' Define topic context.
' Display message.
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)

If Response = vbYes Then                     ' User chose Yes.
    MyString = "Yes"                         ' Perform some action.
Else                                         ' User chose No.
    MyString = "No"                          ' Perform some action.
End If

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b11:cs88").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("v11")
Range("b11:cs88").ClearContents
```

End Sub

Comment: The last two lines need to be inside the If, otherwise it will run regardless of the output.

Comment: Or add an `Exit Sub` after `MyString = "No"`.